# How to use async/await with getBoundingClientRect function

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, coordinates

I'm getting errors in my Angular application because sometimes function getBoundingClientRect() returns zero. I found that it might be an asynchronous operation. So how can I make this part of the code to execute asynchronously. How to use async/await in this case?

```
let right = document.getElementById(rightId);
let rightPosition = right.getBoundingClientRect()
x_right = mainBox.width;
y_right = rightPosition.top - mainBox.top + rightPosition.height/2;
```

I'm using SVG path to draw connection lines between two Angular Material tree components.

This is how I create svg:

```
createSVG() {
  let svgContainer = document.getElementById('svg-main-container');
  this.svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");                                                    
  this.svg.setAttribute('id', 'svg-canvas');
  this.svg.setAttribute('style', `position:absolute;left:0;top:0;display:inline-block;height:100%;width:100%`);
  this.svg.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 100 100');
  this.svg.setAttribute("preserveAspectRatio", "none");
  this.svg.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
  svgContainer.appendChild(this.svg);
  this.svgService.svg = this.svg;
  return this.svg;
}
```

How I connect elements:

```
connectDivs(leftId, rightId) {
  let svgContainer = document.getElementById('svg-component');
  let mainBox = svgContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
  let points = [];

  //left element
  let left = document.getElementById(leftId);
  let leftPosition = left.getBoundingClientRect();
  let x_left = 0;
  let y_left = leftPosition.top - mainBox.top + leftPosition.height/2;

  points.push({x_left, y_left});

  //right element
  let right = document.getElementById(rightId);
  let rightPosition = right.getBoundingClientRect();
  let x_right = mainBox.width;
  let y_right = rightPosition.top - mainBox.top + rightPosition.height/2;

  this.drawConnector(points[0], points[1]);
}
```

This is how I draw connection path:

```
drawConnector(a,b){
  let path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
  let d = `M${a.x_left},${a.y_left} C50,${a.y_left} 50 ${b.y_right} ${b.x_right} ${b.y_right}`;
  path.setAttributeNS(null, "d", d);
  path.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "none");
  path.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "#555");
  path.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", "1.5px");
  path.setAttributeNS(null, "vector-effect", "non-scaling-stroke");
  path.setAttribute("id", this.svgService.draggedElementId);
  path.setAttribute("class", this.svgService.draggedElementId);
  this.svgService.svg.appendChild(path);
}
```

[How my tree connector looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fq9V7.png)

Comment: [That's an XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) : please post your **full** code and a [mcve], and we'll tell you what's wrong with your code !

Comment: @trichetriche I edited my post. I don't think it is a problem with svg because this function returns zero values sometimes not always so that's why I think it might be problem with asynchronous and getBoundingClientRect().

Comment: Well here's your first problem : you're manipulating the DOM yourself. [Haven't you seen that it's terrible practice ?](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEU_frFR838FR838&ei=j9qtXNjxKa24gweuupzABw&q=Angular+6+dom+manipulation&oq=Angular+6+dom+manipulation&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i203j0i22i30.3231.5349..5514...0.0..0.108.1490.12j4......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0j0i10i203j0i22i10i30.3YgvNbuIEu0)

Comment: @trichetriche no I haven't, I'm beginner in Angular, but thanks I will change it and see if it helps.

Comment: then I highly suggest you start with [the official documentation](https://angular.io/docs) before starting using Angular !

Comment: `problem with asynchronous and getBoundingClientRect()` sure, but there is no asynchrony with `getBoundingClientRect` ... so the issue is with your lack of understanding of the asynchrony in your code, and you're probably calling `getBoundingClientRect` *too soon* or something - since the code you've shown *never calls* `connectDivs` then the issue is when/how you call that function

Comment: @JaromandaX I call connectDivs when I drop dragged element from one tree on element from second tree.

Comment: there's a difference between code and a "vague" description of what you are doing